# UITableView with Sections and Parsed Data how to create cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I am having trouble setting up my cellForRowAtIndexPath with Sections. If I were to just show all "tracks" without separations of sections by "topics" then it works fine.

```
Track *aTrack = [appDelegate.tracks objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = aTrack.track_title;
```

I have already set up my numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, titleForHeaderInSection. Those all works fine. But I don't really know how to setup cellForRowAtIndexPath.

After researching some more the best way seems to use a NSDictionary to display my cells...

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [sectionTopicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Tracks"];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to make a MutableArray(sectionTopicArray) that is gonna hold all my Dictionaries? I can see the following in my head but just don't know how to word it in code.

```
sectionTopicArray
[0] Dictionary 1 with key Tracks
    Track1
    Track2
    Track3
[1] Dictionary 2 with key Tracks
    Track4
[2] Dictionary 3 with key Tracks
    Track5
    Track6

basically I'm thinking...
Section0 = Dictionary1 = Topic1 
Section1 = Dictionary2 = Topic2 
Section2 = Dictionary3 = Topic3
```

Comment: Where does the track data live?  Is it in a SQLite DB on the device, does it reside in memory, or is it fetched as needed from the net?

Comment: @John its XML parsed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use nested Arrays.

Create the DataArray:

```
    NSArray *dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    // Section 0
                       track1,                      //  Item 0
                       track2,                      //  Item 1
                       track3,                      //  Item 2  (indexpath 0.2)
                       nil],
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    // Section 1
                       track4,                      //  Item 0  (indexpath 1.0)
                       nil],
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    // Section 2
                       track5,                      // Item 0
                       track6,                      // Item 1   (indexpath 2.1)
                       nil],
                      nil];
```

Access Object in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
Track *trackAtIndexPath = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.section] objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

You can create section titles somehow like this:

```
    NSArray *sectionTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"Section 0",
                          @"Section 1",
                          @"Section 2",
                          nil];
```

Should be clear how to access them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmm...sure, I have also thought about that. But how would you do that in a loop. Since my data is not static and can change if the XML gets changed or updated.

Comment: you just use NSMutableArray instead of those NSArrays, loop through your data and add it at the right location. You could use `[[dataArray objectAtIndex:section] addObject:track]` or something like this to add the tracks to your sections. And if you have to add data to a section that is not already in you dataArray you just add the corresponding Section-Array `[dataArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];`